Adding greek characters in a certain typeset
I'm trying to add Greek characters in a certain typeset (courier new) with the addition of a tilde, to stay consistent with a schematic I've already designed. But I'm having trouble adding it in to LaTeX, what I have tried so far is:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \texttt{\alpha} \\
    \~{\textalpha}
\end{center}
\end{document}


Which is unable to either change the font or else, add the tilde above the character and then,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
     \mathtt{3x^2 \Tilde{\alpha}} \\
     $\mathtt{\~{α}}$
\end{align*}
\end{document}


Which is again unable to change the Greek character to same type set or otherwise add the tilde above the character.
I appreciate this is a very niche problem but is there there any way to do this? Or do I have to use the standard maths font?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippets be compilable! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

No problem, all sorted

Note that both your examples result in errors. The first gives Missing $ inserted because you use \alpha outside of math mode. The second gives Missing } inserted because you use $ inside align. When you remove that you get Unicode character α (U+03B1) not set up for use with LaTeX. Please don't ignore errors, in this case it doesn't make a difference in the output but many times this leads to strange bugs and/or undetected mistakes in the pdf.

Ah ok, I will try to format it better next time. I'm not sure where I found the second example that results in an error, but it doesn't produce the output seen unless within align.

Package courier does not provide an alpha. So you won't get a typewriter alpha using courier. So IMHO $\tilde\alpha$ would be as good or bad as every other combination of non-courier alpha with courier fonts:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{courier}% useless for the alpha
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
$\tilde{\alpha}$ vs. $\widetilde{\alpha}$

\texttt{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\end{document}


To have a typewriter alpha I would suggest to use, e.g.,
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{texgyrecursor}

which needs indeed LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. In this case you could, e.g., use math accent \tilde or \widetilde:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{texgyrecursor}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
$\tilde{\texttt{α}}$ vs. $\widetilde{\texttt{α}}$ vs. $\tilde\alpha$ vs. $\widetilde\alpha$

\texttt{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\end{document}

But here also the tilde (in Greek it would AFAIK be a perispomeni, but this would be another topic) is not using the mono/typewriter font, nevertheless the two \texttt alphas are:

If you find a typewriter/mono opentype font, which contains the unicode character GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA WITH PERISPOMENI U+1FB6 ᾶ, you could even use it directly. TeX Gyre Cursor AFAIK does not provide this character nor the composing character U+0342 to be used with the regular alpha: ᾶ. And unfortunately I do not know any suitable typewriter/mono opentype font with the wanted character.
However for typesetting ancient greek, I would always suggest to use babel:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[greek.ancient,main=english]{babel}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Alpha with tilde in Roman: \foreignlanguage{greek}{\~a}

\ttfamily Alpha with tilde in TypeWriter: \foreignlanguage{greek}{\~a}% not really a typewriter alpha, see below
\end{document}

As the log file states:

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LGR/pcr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LGR/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 8.


here also not Courier but Computer Modern is used for the alpha, because of the missing LGR encoding for Courier, which is because of the missing greek characters. You can see this also in the output:

With LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX you can get an typewriter/mono alpha:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{texgyretermes}
\setmonofont{texgyrecursor}
\usepackage[greek.ancient,main=english]{babel}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Alpha with tilde in Roman: \foreignlanguage{greek}{\~α}

\ttfamily Alpha with tilde in TypeWriter: \foreignlanguage{greek}{\~α} % really typewriter alpha
\end{document}


So IMHO this last example is the best one.

Sorry I have been a bit absent on this post lately. But this is very helpful thank you! It was just what I was looking for.

As a workaround you can first print an empty tilde, then some negative space, then the alpha.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\newcommand{\tttilde}[1]{\~{}\kern-0.5Em#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \texttt{$\alpha$} \\
    \~\textalpha\\
    \tttilde{\textalpha}
\end{center}
\end{document}

Result:


Thanks very much! I was just being a bit pedantic about the problem, but very happy there's a solution.

Note: None of these uses Courier for the alpha, because package courier does not provide an alpha.
